# How to write a text on an animated gif image and preserve the animation in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, image, animation, text

How can i write a text on an animated GIF image (*Font, Size, Location, Text Color*) and **yet preserve the animation** of the image, and all that in Asp.Net.

Here is an example :

BEFORE : [ORIGINAL IMAGE](http://lovelace-media.imgix.net/uploads/365/bf65a420-e9ce-0131-6d2f-0aa0f90d87b4.gif)

AFTER  : [RESULTING IMAGE](https://38.media.tumblr.com/f3e5de3579cd8cd752c05ff2cb750632/tumblr_nwdephfWKq1rohrm2o1_500.gif)

Comment: You can use that GIF as a background image for a div, and then write your content. Is that what you need? or you are expecting the text should be permanently embedded in the GIF?

Comment: i need the text to be embedded within the image, so it wil be downloaded later...